How to use authentication token from Blazor WASM client to authenticate ASP Web API
I'm trying to make both a ASP.NET core Web API and separate WASM blazor (standalone) app, and authenticate both with OIDC/Entra ID.
I can authenticate the Web API as recommended by Microsoft in the MIP/MSAL docs, and similar with WASM Blazor:
Web API:
...

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    ;

//this gives the default of [Authorize] to all requests. We include both schemes so user can access either via OpenID or JWT (Website or API?)
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        , OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        ).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI()
    ;

builder.Services.AddCors(x => x.AddPolicy("policy", new CorsPolicyBuilder().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().Build()));

...

app.UseCors("policy");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

...

WASM:
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<APIHttpClient>(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5033"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CorsAndAuthHttpHandler>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CorsAndAuthHttpHandler>();

builder.Services.Configure<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<MsalProviderOptions>>(
    options =>
    {
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("User.Read");
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("Mail.Read");
    });

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationProvider, GraphAuthenticationProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp =>
{
    return new GraphServiceClient(
        new HttpClient(),
        sp.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationProvider>(),
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/");
});

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(x =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", x.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});

...

public class CorsAndAuthHttpHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CorsAndAuthHttpHandler(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider provider, NavigationManager navigation) : base(provider, navigation)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(new string[] { "https://localhost:5033" });
    }

    protected override HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var resp = base.Send(request, cancellationToken);
        if (resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Found)
        { }
        return resp;
    }
}

At present, I've allowed the Web API to use both JWT/Bearer and OIDC authentication (still a little fuzzy on the difference here, since JWT represents the format while OIDC the process I believe?), so that the user can use the Swagger UI in development or JWT for accessing the API another way. I've also set up allow-all CORS.
For WASM, I've added MSAL authentication using the WASM MSAL libraries, and using Typed HTTPClient, added a handler to attach the MSAL token to all outgoing API calls using localhost for now.
When the WASM app calls the API using the typed HTTPClient, it fails. In the browser tools, I can see the request is made, auth token attached, CORS accepted but the API responds with the error "invalid_token", and attempts to redirect me to Microsoft to authenticate:

Additionally, the redirect to Microsoft authentication server fails:
Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...'
(redirected from 'https://localhost:5033/WeatherForecast') from origin
'https://localhost:5034' has been blocked by CORS policy:
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I can see the graph client requests (authenticated with the same token) work fine in another part of my app, that is configured to just read a few emails from the authenticated users Inbox, so I'm not sure what else I have to do to get my Web API working.

You are getting a COORs error which usually means the website is being block in your network.  It could be for other reasons as well.  You may need to disable a proxy.  You are trying to get weather data and getting a status 302 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302).  HTTP/1/0 is stream mode and HTTP/1.1 is chunk mode.  You are using chunk and maybe changing to stream mode will solve issue.  Chunk mode requires a 100 continue to be sent after each chunk is received.  I've have had issue with chunk mode with c#.

Are you connecting to a VM?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-broken-secure-channel

@jdweng I'm not connecting to a vm no, both the controllers api and blazor webassembly standalone app are on the same machine, just on 2 different ports. As for the CORS issue, I think this is because the API is rejecting my token, and the configuration of the API instructs the caller to redirect to the login page for microsoft, but that redirect fails because of some secondary CORS validation. The MSAL library in the WASM client allows redirection to the microsoft login page just fine when doing the initial authentication, which is extra confusing

MSAL is returning 200 OK?  You are using Graph which uses OAUTH2 (not Windows Authentication).  Most systems are moving from Windows to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 works on Windows, MAC, and Linux.  OAuth2 is a two step authentication.  Step 1 is to get the token/cookie.  Step 2 is to perform query using token.  The token has a lifetime that can be minutes or days.  You can try doing Wasm.  Then do your query without getting a token and see if it works.  Then you know if issue is really the token.

See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/security-101/what-is-openid-connect-oidc?ef_id=k_Cj0KCQjwlZixBhCoARIsAIC745DhvpqjEyfKbca2QeM0qQtYF9OnVdgud3-W-sk0DgNA4T99oHjNf6gaAsPSEALw_wcB_k&OCID=AIDcmmdamuj0pc_SEM__k_Cj0KCQjwlZixBhCoARIsAIC745DhvpqjEyfKbca2QeM0qQtYF9OnVdgud3-W-sk0DgNA4T99oHjNf6gaAsPSEALw_wcB_k_&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwlZixBhCoARIsAIC745DhvpqjEyfKbca2QeM0qQtYF9OnVdgud3-W-sk0DgNA4T99oHjNf6gaAsPSEALw_wcB

@jdweng hi yes the MSAL auth process is going thru fine on the WASM client, and I can call graph using the token, but when I pass it to the Web API, it doesn't work to authenticate the user.

When you use Webapi what is the status code returned in the response?  Don't assume it is authentication.  It could be the Role.  Does it work without COORs?  Is issue the Frontend (HTTP client/server) or the backend to Swagger?  What is connection string to swagger?

Response is in the screenshot "302 - Found", which means redirected, but I think that is coming from the auth middleware in the API saying "Bearer error = invalid_token" and redirecting me to login. Without Cors it just reports a generic CORS error when trying. Connection to api is just "https://localhost:5033"

Read the last two postings at following : https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/18oaamp/devise_302_infinite_redirect_loop_when_developing/
